# Spring Data JPA How to use Kotlin nulls instead of Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a Spring Boot app with Spring Data JPA and Kotlin, and I've noticed that in `CrudRepository` there is the following method:

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

I'm using Kotlin, though, which has much more fluent ways of dealing with nulls than `Optional`. Does anyone know how I would convert that method to work like this?

```
fun findById(id: ID): T?
```

When I extend `Repository` itself and create a repo with that signature I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Optional cannot be cast to com.books.Book
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As of Spring Data Lovelace SR4 / Spring Boot 2.1.2, a `CrudRepository.findByIdOrNull(id: ID): T? = findById(id).orElse(null)` Kotlin extension now provides out of the box a way to retrieve nullable entities in Spring Data.

If for performance reasons you would like to avoid the usage of `Optional<T>` wrapper, be aware that you have also the possibility to create a custom interface with a `findFooById(id: ID): T?` function. Query execution is store specific, but and most are using internally nullable values and will avoid the cost of `Optional<T>` wrapper. Notice this overhead should be negligible for most use cases, so using the builtin extension is recommended method.

See [DATACMNS-1346](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1346) for more details.

Comment: How can I use this kotlin extension? Do I need to do anything special? I get unresolvedReference when trying to use I from a repo that extends `CrudRepository `

Comment: Nevermind, had to import it from `import org.springframework.data.repository.findByIdOrNull`

Comment: However defining methods like `findById(id: Id): T?` in your own base interface that extends `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` doesn't work. You'll get "class java.util.Optional cannot be cast to class ..." errors. You have to define methods for each specific type, e.g. `findById(id: ThingId): Thing?` instead of the generic variant above.

Answer (score 20):

**Update 12/2018:**

An upcoming change in the Spring Data framework will make this answer obsolete. The update basically does the same as this answer: define an appropriate extension function. Please see [Sébastien Deleuze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672633/1788806) for further details.

**Original answer:**

As you correctly stated, you don't need `Optional` in Kotlin, because handling nullability in a concise manner is a build in language feature.

You could create your own extension function to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
fun <T, ID> CrudRepository<T, ID>.findOne(id: ID): T? = findById(id).orElse(null)
```

and use it like this:

```
val fruit: Fruit? = fruitRepository.findOne(id)
```

<sub>Thanks to [Giordano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431668/giordano) who showed me a way to make the function more concise.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Short version of [Sébastien Deleuze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672633/238134): Just define a **function with a nullable return type**:

```
interface UserRepository : Repository<User, String> {

  // throws EmptyResultDataAccessException, if no user is found
  fun findByUsername(username: String): User     

  // return null, if no user is found
  fun findByFirstname(firstname: String?): User? 
}
```

See Spring Data Reference [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.kotlin).

Comment: A VERY important thing not to forget here is to make the ARGUMENT nullable also (like it is also in the example in the reference). Didn't do it and sat a good few hours trouble-shooting. It must have to do with that a `String` in Java can be `null` (and thus corresponds to a nullable `String?` in Kotlin) whereas a `long` in Java is primitive and can never be `null` so it maps well with `Long` in Kotlin... so it's all about helping the compiler map signatures!