# How to properly query entities in Spring JPA with Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am migrating my application to the latest Spring Data and I am struggling to do it properly.

Imagine I have a repository with just one method, in order to additionally query my entities by name:

```
@Repository
interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
   fun findByName(name: String): Foo
}
```

According to the docs, in such situation - if entity is not found - an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` will be thrown.

However, I also want to be able to query entities by id. If I use `findById`, the result will be `Optional<Foo>`. Another option is to use `getOne`, which on the other hand will result in `EntityNotFoundException` if not found.

So, is there any way other than moving everything to `Optional`, to have uniform API in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **question mark** with returned type of your query method as 'equivalent' to **Optional**:

```
interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
   fun findByName(name: String): Foo?
}
```

Then you can use your method with [elvis-operator](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

```
val foo = repo.findByName("bar") ?: Foo("bar")
repo.findByName("bar") ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("foo not found")
```

More info: [Kotlin’s java.util.Optional API Equivalents](http://4comprehension.com/kotlins-java-util-optional-equivalents/)

Comment: I know that, but still `findById` would expose different API with `Optional` - I am looking for a unified way of querying by id and name

Comment: Using nullable types isn't the same as an Optional. It's similar, but Optional is a wrapper, where as nullable is either a class, or not. Also, you can still access Optional in Kotlin.

Comment: The accepted answer in this question has a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143127/spring-data-jpa-how-to-use-kotlin-nulls-instead-of-optional

Comment: no you cannot use like this. it will fail for sure.