# Kotlin Type Mismatch: Taking String from URL path variable and using it as an ID

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

My Spring Boot Application in Kotlin has a POST endpoint defined like this:

```
fun postTermin( @PathVariable("pathID") pathID: String, @Validated @RequestBody termin: RequestBody): ResponseEntity<Appointment> {
    return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
}
```

I'd like to take that "pathID" and use it to find an entity from a repository like so:

```
myRepository.findById(pathID)
```

The CRUDRepository I'm calling there is for an Entity "Dealer" where the ID is defined as:

```
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", length = 10, nullable = false)
 open var id: String = ""
```

The Problem: I get this compile error:

> Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Optional<Dealer!> but Dealer?
> was expected

What's the problem here? Why the "Optional"?

Comment: Assuming you're calling [`CrudRepository#findById(ID)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-), then the return type of that method is `java.util.Optional<T>`.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Spring Data JPA How to use Kotlin nulls instead of Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143127/spring-data-jpa-how-to-use-kotlin-nulls-instead-of-optional).

Comment: Have you specified the location of the pathID with curly bracers in the post mapping like so : 
path/to/post/{pathID}

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Slaw really helped.

As described in [Spring Data JPA How to use Kotlin nulls instead of Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143127/spring-data-jpa-how-to-use-kotlin-nulls-instead-of-optional) there's also a "findByIdOrNull" function for CRUDRepository, i had missed that.
For my use case, that works.